# How to empty input fields from a pop-up window after submitting - Vue - laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, input, bootstrap-modal

My page exist of a table where I can add new rows. If you want to add a new row a pop-up window appear where the new values can be added.
This new data is then saved to the database after submitting. If I again want to add a new row the input fields, they should be cleared.
The method I use, is working but isn't very clear.

Note: My code shows only a part of the input fields, to make it more clear. My pop-up window actually contains 20 input fields.

I would like to clear them all at once instead of clearing them one by one (like I am doing now).
Because I am already doing this for defining the v-model, pushing the new data to the database directly on the page and via post axios request. 
Is there a cleaner way to do this?
Thanks for any input you could give me.

This is my code:

## html part

```
        <div class="col-2 md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sx" @click="showModal('add')">Add New</button>
                <b-modal :ref="'add'" hide-footer title="Add new" size="lg">
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <b-form-group label="Category">
                                <b-form-input type="text" v-model="newCategory"></b-form-input>
                            </b-form-group>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <b-form-group label="Name">
                                <b-form-input type="text" v-model="newName" placeholder="cd4"></b-form-input>
                            </b-form-group>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <b-form-group label="Amount">
                                <b-form-input type="number" v-model="newAmount" ></b-form-input>
                            </b-form-group>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-8">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div class="mt-2">
                                <b-button @click="hideModal('add')">Close</b-button>
                                <b-button @click="storeAntibody(antibodies.item)" variant="success">Save New Antibody</b-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </b-modal>
        </div>
```

## js part

```
        <script>   
        import { async } from 'q';
            export default {
                props: ['speciedata'],
                data() {
                    return {
                        species: this.speciedata,
                        newCategory: '',
                        newName: '',
                        newAmount:'',
                    } 
                },
                computed: {

                },
                mounted () {
                },
                 methods: {
                    showModal: function() {
                        this.$refs["add"].show()
                    },
                    hideModal: function(id, expId) {
                        this.$refs['add'].hide()
                    },    
                    addRow: function(){
                        this.species.push({
                            category: this.newCategory,
                            name: this.newName,
                            amount: this.newAmount,
                        })
                    },
                storeSpecie: async function() {
                    axios.post('/specie/store', {
                        category: this.newCategory,
                        name: this.newName,
                        amount: this.newAmount,
                    })
                    .then(this.addRow())
                    // Clear input
                    .then(
                        this.newName = '',
                        this.newCategory = '',
                        this.newAmount = '',
                    )
                    .then(this.hideModal('add'))
                },
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your data of vuejs app , you have to set one object for displaying modal data like `modalData` then to reset data you can create one function and set default value by checking type of value using loop through modalData object keys

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message:"Hi there",
    modalData:{
       key1:"value1",
       key2:"value2",
       key3:"value3",
       key4:5,
       key5:true,
       key6:"val6"
    }
  },
   methods: {
     resetModalData: function(){
        let stringDefault="";
        let numberDefault=0;
        let booleanDefault=false;
      
        Object.keys(this.modalData).forEach(key => {  
        if(typeof(this.modalData[key])==="number"){
            this.modalData[key]=numberDefault;
          }else if(typeof(this.modalData[key])==="boolean")            {
           this.modalData[key]=booleanDefault;
          }else{
            // default type string
            this.modalData[key]=stringDefault;
          }
        
        });

     }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
   {{modalData}}
   <br/>
   <button @click="resetModalData">Reset Modal Data</button>
</div>
```

update : in your case :

```
data:{

        species: this.speciedata,
        modalData:{
        newCategory: '',
        newName: '',
        newAmount:''
      } 
 },
```

and after storing data :

```
storeSpecie: async function() {
                    axios.post('/specie/store', {
                        category: this.newCategory,
                        name: this.newName,
                        amount: this.newAmount,
                    })
                    .then(()=>{
                    this.addRow();
                    this.resetModalData();
                    this.hideModal('add')
                    }

                },
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there also the possibility, that it could be done automatically without the need for pushing the reset button?

Comment: @Nemo ,  reset button is for example purpose only help to understand , but you have to call `resetModalData` function white reseting data

Answer (score 0):

In native Javascript you get the `reset()` method.

Here is how it is used :

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

It will clear every input in the form.

Comment: I am not working with a form. So, do I need to make a form in order to reset my data

Comment: It would be cleaner, even for submitting your datas. As you want